# Prove that for any real numbers x,y,z $3(xy+yz+zx)\le(x+y+z)^2\le3(x^2+y^2+z^2)$

Tags: inequality, summation, symmetric-polynomials

I am working through a pure maths book as a hobby and have come to inequalities.
A question asks:

Prove that for any real numbers x,y,z $3(xy+yz+zx)\le(x+y+z)^2\le3(x^2+y^2+z^2)$

I expanded to get

$(x+y+z)^2=(x^2+y^2+z^2)+2(xy+xz+yz)$ but I cannot get from this to the answer. I am particularly puzzled how/why the 3 crops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty standard form of rearrangement inequality.
Without loss of generality, assume $$z\le y \le x$$
Then, $$z^2\le y^2\le x^2$$
Rearrangement inequality states, if two sequences,$$a_1,a_2...a_n$$ and $$b_1,b_2...b_n$$ are similarly sorted, either increasing or decreasing, then we have
$$a_nb_n+...a_2b_2+a_1b_1\ge a_1b_n+...a_nb_1$$
Or in words, the maximum of the sum occurs when similarly sorted and the minimum when oppositely sorted.
Applying rearrangment inequality on the set $x,y,z$ twice, we get
$$xy+yz+zx\le x^2+y^2+z^2~~~~(1)$$
Adding $2xy+2yz+2zx$ to both sides,we get the first part of the inequality,
$$3(xy+yz+zy)\le(x+y+z)^2$$ and since $$ (x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)\le x^2+y^2+z^2 +2(x^2+y^2+z^2) from (1)$$
$$(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)\le 3(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$ we have proved the 2nd part of the inequality as well.

Comment: Your answer was helpful to me, in particular because I had never come across the concept of rearrangement inequality so it opened up a new area.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a new area as rearrangement and weighted inequalities are merely the next portion of inequalities after the basic ones, but yes,I'll admit it was extremely intriguing to me as well when I first encountered them.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, go ahead with your method:

$$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+da)~~~~(1)$$
Due to AM-GM $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$ etc, we know
$$a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab+bc+ca~~~~(2)$$
Add (1) and (2) to get $$(a+b+c)^2 \ge 3(ab+bc+ca)$$
Re-write (2) as $$ab+bc+ca \le a^2+b^2+c^2 ~~~~~(3)$$
then add rwice of (2) to (1) to get
$$(a+b+c)^2 \le 3(a^3+b^2+c^2)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$(x+y+z)^2-3(xy+xz+yz)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\geq0.$$
$$3(x^2+y^2+z^2)-(x+y+z)^2=\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: This looks like an elegant and succinct answer. Unfortunately for me, it is way beyond my competence. I never expected the sum of a series and cannot see where it comes from. Indeed, I do not understand the term $\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2$. It has never appeared in my text book so far. I'm hoping there is an alternative  algebraic method.

Comment: @Steblo  $\sum\limits_{cyc}(x-y)^2$ it's just $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2.$ I hope now it's clear.

Comment: @Steblo this is also how the thing appears when writing "the matrix" of each quadratic form and subtracting  in pairs.

Answer (score 1):

If $A=xy+yz+zy$, $B=(x+y+z)^2$, $C=x^2+y^2+z^2$ then you have already shown:
$$ B = C+2A $$

Now let’s proove: $A\leq C$. $A$ is a form given by $\langle X, MX\rangle$ where $X=(x,y,z)$ and $M(x,y,z)=(y,z,x)$. Then
$$ A = \langle X, MX\rangle \leq ||X||\,||MX||= ||X||^2 = C$$

Thus $B-3A = C-A \geq 0$, which proves the first inequality. Also we get $B=C+2A\leq 3C$. This proves the second inequality.